# DMP Search Model - Terminology

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, search-and-matching

In the most basic Diamond-Mortensen-Pissarides (DMP) model we have the variable $V$ which represents the present discounted value of expected profits from a vacant job. The corresponding Bellman equation is

$rV = -pc + q(\theta)(J-V)$

Where $pc$ is the cost of a vacant job per unit of time, $q(\theta)$ is the rate at which vacancies are filled and $J$ is the present discounted value of expected profits from an occupied job. If I think of a vacancy as an asset for the firm the Bellman equation makes sense but how can a vacancy be an asset?

What I don't understand is the intuitive meaning of $V$. How can a vacant job result in profits for the hiring firm? Furthermore, my textbook says

> In equilibrium all profit opportunities from new jobs are exploited, driving rents from vacant jobs to zero. Therefore the equilibrium condition for the supply of vacant jobs is $V=0$

Again, how are there 'rents' from having a vacant job?

Answer (score 1):

A vacant job is an **asset** if we consider that the firm can match with a worker and get a positive expected profit. Firms post vacancies up to a point where $V=0$. If $V$ were positive, more firms would enter, would post additional vacancies, and would get a `rent' (by matching with worker).

Comment: That clarifies things a bit. However, we said that $J$ was the expected profits from an occupied job. And it is only then that the firm will realise the profits. So $V$ is simply a hypothetical? Clearly the vacancy in and of itself cannot generate any profits, it is only when they match with an unemployed worker that profits are realised.   I feel like I am overcomplicating things but the idea of a vacancy being an asset is just too strange for me.